# Google Analytics - New & Old Domain Filtering

Tags: google-analytics, 301-redirect

I have two domains associated with the same hosting account.  Domain A was the one I had purchased when I first set up my website, but I didn't like it all that much and it was getting low ranks, and so I bought domain B and 301'd links from domain A to domain B. Now I would like to know if there is any way I can filter page views on Google Analytics based on the domain used to access the website, so that I can know if it is worth to keep the old domain associated with the account. Is there any easy way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You are using a 301 redirect to move traffic from the old domain to the new domain, so there will be no referring data in Google analytics.

Instead, you can [tag your redirect URLs](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55518) to indicate that they come from the old domain.  What you need to do is change the 301 redirect target to something like `http://new-domain.com/path/to/page?utm_source=old-domain.com&utm_medium=redirect`.

All visitors from old-domain.com will now display in the Traffic Source reports.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still naïve with Analytics, but I think that this is one way to roughly achieve what you are asking.

1) Make sure the webpages on Domain A have the same Analytics code as Domain B

2) Go to: `Audience > Visitors Flow`

3) Click on Domain A (it will show the flow of visitors from Domain A to domain B)

4) Select 'View only this segment'

Comment: Actually, maybe since you are giving out 301's it might be the case that this will not work. I'd try out @donaldthe's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can look under traffic sources then referrals and see how many visits your domain A has sent to your new domain.

Comment: Visitors fom 301's don't display in refferals